# Select2 Remote Data to select multiple items

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am currently working on a project and I am using select2.js for it. It is working well.

But now Client wants me to make him able to select multiple items in the same

Is it possible to select several options when we receive data remotely for the select2 library?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible

just add `multiple: true` option to select2 options. like:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  multiple:true,
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/select2/repos',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        type: 'public'
      }
      return query;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: do not forget to use class="js-data-example-ajax" for select element